# UK student visa refused but they made an error in calculation

Tags: united-kingdom

I submitted an application for a student visa on June 19. I received the decision today which was a refusal. When I read the refusal letter, it says that I need a total of £32,025 pounds for the remaining tuition and maintenance fees.

That is not correct: I'm applying for a PGCE which is one year. It costs £13,920. I already paid £2475, so £11,445 remains; the maintenance fees should be 9 x £1,015 = £9,135. The total I should have in my bank account should be at least £20,580 pounds. My Saudi bank statement shows £23,529 pounds.

I don't understand how they calculated the £32,025 or where they getting it from. Would this means that they made a mistake? What should I do in this case?

Quick note: The course starts on Sept 4 and ends the following year on July 6.

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

Comment: Did they somehow double-count your remaining fees when they calculated the amount?  £11445 + £11445 + (9 months)*(£1015/month) = £32025.

Comment: You're right. That could be it, yet I still I don't know what to do in this case?

Comment: Given Michael Seifert's calculation, this looks like a good case for requesting administrative review, as described on page 2 of your scan. You're not objecting to any _judgment_ of the ECO, but to what appears to be a plain arithmetic error in the processing. That's exactly  the kind of thing that administrative review is meant to correct. (But make sure not to raise any _new_ arguments or new documentation in the review request).

Comment: ***If you believe the decision made by the Entry Clearance Officer was incorrect you may apply for Administrative Review of your case.*** It seems pretty obvious to me what you ought to do next...

Comment: @Yousef do you mind letting us know what happened then? That would definitely help a lot of future readers